# Amp Javascript adds ineligible tags to the page

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I am using gatsby js to build my static amp page and you can see the final html output in the [search console](https://search.google.com/test/amp?id=khLFg07BIgoKn_XaRuHfIQ). You can see that the generated html passes amp validation. That test passes because I copy and pasted the generated html.

However the website fails because on page load the official amp script `<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>` adds ineligible tags. If I remove the script, the html stays the same. There are other scripts but I am 99% sure it's ^ one because I tried removing them one by one.

The script adds things like amp-version i-amphtml-sizer in the css and changes other things on the page. I am not sure why it would add these tags because `v0.js` is recommended by amp.

You can see the failing page here.
https://search.google.com/test/amp?id=aClwacaTtbw5q7-Dm3glPg&skip_amp_follow=true

**If someone can point me to the original `amp v0.js` I will be truly grateful.  The CDN version is uglified+transpiled and it's really hard to debug my issue.**

Comment: Hi, what about this url parameter? Does it show errors in developer console? https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/validation-workflow/validate_amp/#browser-developer-console

Comment: No, the validator passes. https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.michaelharwinlaw.com%2Fwhat-is-a-career-criminal%2Famp%2F

Comment: 1) download repo from github.com/ampproject/amphtml
2) run 'yarn install'
3) run 'gulp' (it starts server on localhost:8000)

There are 3 options in settings (JavaScript Serve Mode):
- Default - Unminified AMP JavaScript is served from the local server. For local development you will usually want to serve unminified JS to test your changes.
- Compiled
- CDN

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time but I actually found the original file in `Amp-Html` repo. The problem was cache related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by amp cache. I had to follow this guide to invalidate the cache for all my amp pages.

https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache.